# ASP error when moving site to new host

Tags: iis, asp-classic

I have a site that is built in Classic ASP with ADODB Access databases. I'm moving to a new host and now getting an error for code that runs fine on current host.

> ADODB.RecordSet error '800a0c93' operation is not allowed in this
>   context

I researched the problem and it appears that the problem is related to the way I open recordsets. by default recordsets open forward only. I'm trying to move previous in the code.

I checked and the code to open the RS is:

```
rsChurches.open strSQL1, adoCON, 3,3
```

3 = adOpenStatic.

This code should work as it runs fine on my current server. I checked the application pool. it's .net framework 2.0 classic with 32 bit applications enabled like the current server.

Answer (score 1):

After looking at the server all day, I changed the cursor type to 2 and it worked.

```
rsChurches.cursortype = 2
rsChurches.open strSQL1, adoCON
```

I'm not sure why the new server didn't like type 3.